# What does the Render and Preview of the Samples section do?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, light, performance

Yesterday, i put my animation to render, it went fine. But one thing that bothers me is: What is the Render and Preview? I actually discovered that the Render is something like the quality, so i keep it on 128 because it is fast and the quality is great for me. But what is Preview? And what should i keep it on? Any help would be appreciated.

I use the CUDA with GPU Compute rendering (cycles). I'm new to Blender so i may seem silly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview setting determines the quality of the rendering in your viewport, when you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Since it's always refreshing and recalculating the image whenever you change the view or a material setting or else, you will probably want it to have far lower settings than your render settings.

Answer (score 2):

The Render samples is for your final render when you hit the render button

The Preview is when you switch your 3D view to be rendered. Its a quick view.

[image]

Comment: And what happens when i change it to 0? And does decreasing it make my Blender performance generally better?

Comment: If you set the preview samples to 0 (zero) it will render samples into infinity or until something in the scene has changed, in which case the preview render will restart. You cannot set the render samples to 0.

Yes, when the preview samples has been completely rendered it will stop rendering and thus, the resources used while rendering will be freed up to do other things.