# I can't render animation in Blender with the rendered model and a picture background

Tags: rendering, animation

I have created in Blender a Star Destroyer Model from scratch, with textures and all, and rendered it to an image ( it's attached here ).
[image]

It looks great in my opinion. So I decided to create an animation with it. It is supposed to look like this: https://youtu.be/ljvxzYJhRYo ( it's my own video on my Youtube channel).
The animation above was made with opengl render and my problem is that it doesn't have the background that I put as well as any textures and displacements on the Star Destroyer like in the rendered image attached here.
I tried to render also with the normal render button and always it rendered a black screen. I am 100% sure that my camera angle is right so I know that is not the problem.
This is how I want to be the animation, of course with all the textures and background image.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qc9WmDYXFs&feature=youtu.be (my own video recording of my screen)

Can you tell me why my normal rendering doesn't work? This is how it looks when I render with the normal button NOT opengl:
[image] 
The renderer doesn't do anything and I don't know why.

You would help me a lot if you could help me with this project of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you familiarize yourself a bit more with the software. The background images you see in the 3d viewport will NEVER be rendered. In order to get a background image you can use the compositor:

[How to composite in a background picture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture)

As for the rendering to black screen, check the compositor as well (is everything set up correctly) and check if the light sources work. (This you can check in the viewport by changing to the cycles preview)

[What does the Render and Preview of the Samples section do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93904/what-does-the-render-and-preview-of-the-samples-section-do)

a relevant tutorial is 
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06A_l95vJWw)